# fastapi swagger not sending the token with the url

Tags: authorization, fastapi

The fastapi swagger not sending token with the header. Even though i login through the authorization button of swagger.
this is the url it is showing: curl -X GET "http://localhost:8000/locations/?limit=100" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer undefined"

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="/users/createtoken")

Comment: The same issue, except I parse Authorization through Depends and method with declared argument authorization: str = Header(...)

Answer (score 6):

If you want FastAPI's SwaggerUI to include your token in the API calls, make sure that your `/users/createtoken` endpoint is including the 2 required keywords in the response.

1. `access_token`: this should be your token value
2. `token_type`: the value of this should be `Bearer`

So your response should be something like,

```
{
    access_token: 'abcdefg12345token',
    token_type: 'Bearer'
}
```

If your endpoint is returning,

```
{
    token: 'abcdefg12345token'
}
```

any SwaggerUI API calls will just show `undefined` for the token bearer value.