# how to make fastapi swagger read token from custom responsebody of login API

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, jwt, swagger, fastapi

The fastAPI swagger only sending token in the header when my login API return body is

```
{
  "access_token": "JWT Token",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60222034/fastapi-swagger-not-sending-the-token-with-the-url), FastAPI Swagger only works when access_token and token_type is available in the login responsebody.

However I want FastAPI Swagger to read the value from this responsebody Type

```
{
  "success": true,
  "status": "success",
  "error": null,
  "payload": {
  "access_token": "JWT Token",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
  }
}
```

Any heads up on how to define OAuth2 to read access_token and token_type from custom Login responsebody?